# Capacitive power supply

Tags: power-supply

What is the role of the BJT and capacitor C2 in the capacitive power supply circuit shown below?

[image: Capacitive Power Supply Circuit]

Comment: The BJT is a current amplifier. The capacitor stores charge. What is the context? Is it taken directly from an exam you are taking in school? What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are implementing a "charge pump" that increases the available output current. It's easier to see if you redraw the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHXXFT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When "Line" goes negative, C2 charges through D1 and D4. Q1 is cut off, as are D2 and D3.

When "Line" goes positive, it not only supplies current through D3 to the load, it also switches on Q1. This pulls the negative end of C2 up to the "Neutral" voltage, allowing it to discharge through D2 and supply additional current to the load.

---

Note that the same increase in available current could have been achieved with an ordinary 4-diode bridge rectifier. However, this circuit has the advantage that the negative side of the regulator remains directly tied to neutral.

Comment: How does switching on of the transistor pulls -ve of capacitor to neutral? The collector itself is at neutral, so how does the collector current flow actually?

Comment: @JuneStar_2918: The collector current flows through the emitter into the negative (bottom) end of the capacitor. At the same time, current flows out of the positive end of the capacitor, through D2, to the load. This current flow discharges C2. Q1 is saturated, so its Vce drop is very small. You can think of it as a switch that shorts neutral directly to the negative end of the capacitor during the positive half-cycles.

Comment: I can't actually figure out where the collector current comes from.

Comment: @JuneStar_2918: To complete the loop, the current flowing out of the positive end of C2 flows through the load, and back to the collector via the neutral line.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: How is  the negative side of the regulator not  tied to neutral  if we use a normal four diode bridge rectifier  considering that this is a non isolated power supply. Also what is the advantage of the negative side of regulator  directly tied to neutral.

Comment: @CSThakur: With a bridge rectifier, the negative side of the regulator is "tied" alternately to the neutral and the line, depending on which one is more negative. To be honest, I don't know why there might be an advantage to having it directly tied -- the whole thing needs to be double-insulated anyway. Perhaps something to do with EMC?